# Why does my ActionListener only work for one of my buttons?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield, filewriter

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.* ;

class plugin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        plugin gui = new plugin();
    }

    JTextField progname = new JTextField("Program Name");
    JButton pnameok = new JButton("Ok");

    JTextField endtxt = new JTextField("Type of file");
    JButton endok = new JButton("Ok");

    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop the Server");

    public plugin() {
        super();
        add(pnl);
        pnl.add(stop);
        pnl.add(progname);
        pnl.add(pnameok);

        pnl.add(endtxt);
        pnl.add(endok);

        pnameok.addActionListener(this);
        endok.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {

        if(event.getSource() == endok) {
            try {
                String end = endtxt.getText();
                FileWriter endfile = new FileWriter( end + ".txt" );
            }
            catch( IOException e ) {
                boolean uselessend = true;
            }

            if(event.getSource() == pnameok) {
                try {
                    String pname = progname.getText();
                    FileWriter pnamefile = new FileWriter( pname + ".txt" );
                }
                catch( IOException e1 ) {
                    boolean uselesspname = true;
                    try {
                        FileWriter pnamefileuse = new FileWriter( "error" );
                    }
                    catch( IOException e2 ) {
                        boolean completeandutterfail = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, enter `yay` into Program Name and `exe` into Type of file and click both of the OK buttons, I get a new file called `exe.txt` but no file called `yay.txt`. Why is this?

Comment: Did you try debugging it by printing something in each for-loop to make sure they are both being executed appropriately when a button is clicked?

Comment: yes and in the for loop for pnameok it didn't execute that either

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have definitely done something stupid. And that is there is a mess of curly brackets all over. Remove an end bracket (`}`) from the end and add it immediately after this code:

```
catch( IOException e ) {
    boolean uselessend = true;
}
```

So it becomes this:

```
  catch( IOException e ) {
    boolean uselessend = true;
  }
}
```

That should fix it.
Also as a sidenote: 
1. Make first letter of your class name capital. (e.g. `Plugin`). 
2. Indent your code for better readibility.
3. You might want to add `e.printStackTrace()` for debugging in `catch` part of the exceptions.

Comment: thanks it did fix it. I really am stupid and thanks again

Comment: @33CoolyDude33. Perhaps you want to accept my answer if it fixed it.